# Bug with screen sharing with RTCMulticonnection from Chrome to Mozilla

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am creating p2p application to share video and screen from Chrome to Mozilla. When I work with Chrome on both sides, it works fine. But when Mozilla is receiving screensharing video, I get a problem.

To start screenshare I do the following in Chrome:

```
connection.addStream({screen: true, oneway: true}
```

On the client side I have this callback:

```
connection.onstream = function (e) {
 // handle input stream
}
```

With Mozilla this callback is not launched, but I see flickering on my main webcam stream: few frames from webcam and few frames from screenshare continiously.

How can I fix this? Is this Mozilla bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was migrating to SimpleRTC (http://simplewebrtc.com). This is same sort of library, but it is updated regularly to reflect browsers/API changes. The challange was signalling layer, because it uses special (opensource) library on top of socketio to handle chat rooms. But now screensharing works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

it you're adding more than one stream to a single peerconnection, you may be hitting the fact that Chrome and Firefox support different dialects of [SDP](https://webrtchacks.com/update-anatomy-webrtc-sdp-anton-roman/).

Unless you do translation of the SDP, you'll have to use different peerconnections until [the chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465349) is fixed.

Comment: Philipp, is there any sample code/other evidence that it is possible to hack SDP?

Comment: Well, it doesnt work, it crashes as expplained here: https://github.com/jitsi/sdp-interop/issues/4